# Getting Value of input type time in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, split

i am newbie in angularjs..

This is my form field:

```
input type="time" ng-model=mytime
```

The input type time gives me HH:MM: PM/AM from the above syntax.

I want to get the value of the field one by one using angular js.
how do I get my HH value using angular js ??

Also is there any way to integrate camera plugin using angularjs?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS, use the date filter to control the presentation of the date.

```
<input type="date" ng-model="mytime">
<input type="time" ng-model="mytime"><br>

{{mytime | date : 'd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}
```

For more information, see [AngularJS date Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

---

For `type="date"` and `type="time"` inputs, `ng-model` returns a JavaScript Date object. All the standard Date methods are available.

```
var hours = $scope.mytime.getHours();
var month = $scope.mytime.getMonth();

// etc.
```

For more information, see [MDN JavaScript Reference - Standard Objects - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Nice to notice that ng-model for both date and time has the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split` which will split a string into an array of substrings based on a separator. The hours will then be the first item in the array. You can do this like so:

```
var hours = $scope.mytime.split(';')[0];
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: Thu Jan 01 1970 13:03:00 GMT+0530 (IST) this is inserted in the table.

Comment: how do i get hours and mins from the Sun Apr 03 2016 18:28:10 GMT+0530 (IST) and set it to my html input type time..?  as i m getting an error of datefmt..